# How can i split two different cell to rows in DB2 with SQL Script

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table like this. My problem is that this data is stored nested. I want to fix this with DB2 script code. I did it with Python but im not sure if we can do it with SQL.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BC BCD BCDE | 123 1234 12345 |

I want this table.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BC | 123 |
| 1 | BCD | 1234 |
| 1 | BCDE | 12345 |

Comment: Do you always have 3 distinct values in Columns B and C? If not, do you always have the same number of values in both columns and what is the maximum number of values you can have?

Comment: Columns B and C have up to 10 different values. I have different values ​​each time.

Comment: What if B and C contain unequal number of tokens (each one may have more or less than other in different records)?

Comment: Platform and version of Db2?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein there is no  problem like that, I solved it. The only thing is separating them equally.

Comment: @B.Ozen The question was not about if we have any problem with this. It was about the result you desire in this case. I've tried to guess and provided an answer. If it's not what you expect, then please, provide the desired result on my sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with mytab (A, B, C) as
(
  values
    (1, 'BC BCD BCDE', '123 1234 12345')
  , (2, 'ab cd', '11 22 33')
  , (3, 'ef gh  ij', '44  55')
)  
select t.*, x.tok_b, x.tok_c
from 
  mytab t
, table
(
  select 
    coalesce (c.seq, b.seq) as seq
  , b.tok as tok_b
  , c.tok as tok_c
  from xmltable
  (
    'for $id in tokenize($s, " +") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
    passing t.b as "s"
    columns 
      seq for ordinality
    , tok varchar (20) path '.'
  ) b
  full join xmltable
  (
    'for $id in tokenize($s, " +") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
    passing t.c as "s"
    columns 
      seq for ordinality
    , tok varchar (20) path '.'
  ) c on c.seq = b.seq
) x
```

| A | B | C | TOK_B | TOK_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BC BCD BCDE | 123 1234 12345 | BC | 123 |
| 1 | BC BCD BCDE | 123 1234 12345 | BCD | 1234 |
| 1 | BC BCD BCDE | 123 1234 12345 | BCDE | 12345 |
| 2 | ab cd | 11 22 33 | ab | 11 |
| 2 | ab cd | 11 22 33 | cd | 22 |
| 2 | ab cd | 11 22 33 |  | 33 |
| 3 | ef gh ij | 44 55 | ef | 44 |
| 3 | ef gh ij | 44 55 | gh | 55 |
| 3 | ef gh ij | 44 55 | ij |  |